# cntk image deserializer transform mean_file

Tags: image, transform, cntk

I use the below code to create my mean_file to use in CNTK's image deserializer's transform. I want all values to be 128. I have 64x64x1 images. The file is created perfectly fine, but the model doesn't like it. I get the below error. Any ideas?

Code:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as et
import xml.dom.minidom

data=np.full((64*64),128)

imgSize=64

def saveMean(fname, data):
    root = et.Element('opencv_storage')
    et.SubElement(root, 'Channel').text = '1'
    et.SubElement(root, 'Row').text = str(imgSize)
    et.SubElement(root, 'Col').text = str(imgSize)
    meanImg = et.SubElement(root, 'MeanImg', type_id='opencv-matrix')
    et.SubElement(meanImg, 'rows').text = '1'
    et.SubElement(meanImg, 'cols').text = str(imgSize * imgSize * 1)
    et.SubElement(meanImg, 'dt').text = 'f'
    et.SubElement(meanImg, 'data').text = ' '.join(['%e' % n for n in np.reshape(data, (imgSize * imgSize * 1))])

    tree = et.ElementTree(root)
    tree.write(fname)
    x = xml.dom.minidom.parse(fname)
    with open(fname, 'w') as f:
        f.write(x.toprettyxml(indent = '  '))

saveMean('mean1.xml', data)
```

====================

Error:

RuntimeError: C:\buildslave64\win64_amdocl\master_PackSlave-win64-vc14-shared\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:639: error: (-209) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function cv::arithm_op

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: for some reason, it still wants the mean_file to be 3 channels. So, size of the mean_file should be 64*64*3. And the corresponding values should all be changed to 3 channels in the file.